# InnerHTML for null vs undefined

Tags: javascript, html

Consider this snippet

```js
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = null; // 1
console.log(`After setting null: "${div.innerHTML}"`);
div.innerHTML = undefined; // 2
console.log(`After setting undefined: "${div.innerHTML}"`);
```

Why doesn't the first snippet of `innerHTML` yield `"null"`? I expected the value to be a result of `innerHTML = value` to be same as `String(value)` as it expects a `DOMString`? `String(null)` yields `"null"`.

MDN also mentions the [`ToString`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-tostring) approach which too returns `"null"`. The only thing that *might* hint at this special behavior is this snippet from the page on [`DOMString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString#:%7E:text=Certain%20Web%20APIs%20accepting%20a%20DOMString%20have%20an%20additional%20legacy%20behavior%2C%20where%20passing%20null%20stringifies%20to%20the%20empty%20string%20instead%20of%20the%20usual%20%22null%22.)

> Certain Web APIs accepting a DOMString have an additional legacy
> behavior, where passing null stringifies to the empty string instead
> of the usual "null".

Are there any definitive places (spec or otherwise) where such behavior can be confirmed from?

Comment: Great question, because even if we try to do the comparison: `null == ""`, we get false.

Comment: @NNL993 then again, a bunch of places treat `null` *slightly* differently generally to mean "empty input". The behaviour here shouldn't really be shocking.

Comment: @NNL993: That doesn't say much though because JavaScript's "loose" comparison treats `null` in a special way.

Comment: ```""``` is considered to be a null string

Comment: @Lk77 no, it's considered to be an empty string. There is no such thing as "null string" defined in JS. At most, there is `String(null)` which will give you the string representation of the value `null` but that would be `"null"`.

Comment: that's why i say considered, i know there is no such a thing in the js spec, many devs call `""` a null string, because null is not a string, and `""` is the closest we can get to null but while still beeing a string, `String.prototype.toString(null)` gives `""`

Comment: @Lk77 `String.prototype.toString(null)` makes no real sense to call. You'd get the same result from `String.prototype.toString(42)` : it's still `""` because the parameter to `toString()` is ignored. Using `String.prototype.toString.call(null)` makes a bit more sense if you want to simulate `.toString()` called on `null`, however, the result in that case is an error.

Comment: yeah you right, that what i was thinking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a spec: https://w3c.github.io/DOM-Parsing/#the-innerhtml-mixin

`innerHTML` has the "IDL extended attribute" [`LegacyNullToEmptyString`](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#LegacyNullToEmptyString) which describes this behavior.